# Sphinx - word boundaries

Tags: c, sphinx

How to set the boundaries of words using `Sphinx`?

For example, i want to find a phrase: "some."

But `Sphinx` finds "something"!

I've tried to set `SPH_MATCH_PHRASE)`:

```
sphinx_set_match_mode(sph, SPH_MATCH_PHRASE);
```

Comment: So where's the C (K&R's) part coming here?! Becuase the only sphinx I know is the one described in Greek mythology :)

Comment: Pocket Sphinx is an opensource voice recognition engine with an extensive and easy-to-use C progrramming API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use extended syntax: SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2

And use phrase search operator like:

```
$cl->Query('"some"');
```

Check out the manual: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Check out the manual.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-phrase-boundary